# Calculating the limit of $\frac{x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\sin x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$$ \lim _{x\to 0} \frac{x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\sin x}$$

Okay since sine is bounded ${x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})} \ \ \to 0$

$\sin x\to  0$ Thus we can apply l'hospitals to it .

Applying l'Hospital's we get :

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})(1-2x)}{\cos x}$$ Here We can't find a way out? What would you advice me to do? Is there anyway to compute the limit?

Does this imply that the limit doesn't exist btw? No I don't think so, I think the conditions of the l'Hospital's are just not met.

Comment: [_L'Hopital's rule_](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule)

Comment: @mathbeing No need for it here, though.

Comment: Small l, big H. I guess you need to be a frenchman to say why.

Comment: Is OP even allowed to use l'Hospital rule here? How would one solve the limit he is left over with?

Comment: @ClementC. Obviously no need for it (arguably never). It just bothered me to read 'l'hospital'. Now I am just confused. Is it correct to say 'l'Hospital'?

Comment: The name was Guillaume de l'Hôpital (also spelled Guillaume de l'Hospital, the "os" often became "ô" as in hostel/hôtel). For the capitalization... I don't know for sure, but neither looks like blasphemy to me.

Comment: @Xenidia applying l'Hostpital to the top part should result in [something else](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx(x%5E2+*+sin(1%2Fx))).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easier is to break into a product of limits:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2\sin\tfrac{1}{x}}{\sin x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{\sin x}\cdot \lim_{x\to0}\,x\sin\tfrac{1}{x} = 1\cdot 0 = 0.
$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Can you first calculate the limit below?

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x^2}{\sin\left(x\right)}$$

Afterwards, notice, as you yourself said, that the sine is bounded.

Answer (score 3):

1). Use the standard limit (derivative of $\sin$ at $0$) 
$$
\frac{\sin x}{x} \xrightarrow[x\to 0]{} 1
$$
so that 
$$
\frac{x}{\sin x} \xrightarrow[x\to 0]{} 1
$$
as well.

2). Rewrite
$$
\frac{x^2 \sin\frac{1}{x}}{\sin x}
= x\cdot \frac{x}{\sin x}\cdot \sin\frac{1}{x}
$$

3). Look at the three factors. The one goes to $0$, the second converges to $1$, the last is bounded.

4). Conclude.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}x=1$$

and

$$-x<x\sin(1/x)<x$$

Thus,

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2\sin(1/x)}{\sin(x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac x{\sin(x)}x\sin(1/x)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

You might know that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{\sin(x)} = 1$ and that $\lim_{x\to 0} x \sin(1/x) = 0.$

Answer (score 1):

L Hopital rule says that this is $$ \frac{(x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x}))'}{\cos x}$$ in cero, but the numerator has a discontinuity in the derivate, and the value must be calculated by definition:
$$\lim _{x\to 0} \frac{x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{x}=\lim _{x\to 0} x\sin(\frac{1}{x})=0$$
So the limit is cero.
Another way:
$$\lim _{x\to 0} \frac{x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\sin x}=\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{x}{sin(x)} x\sin(\frac{1}{x})=1*\lim _{x\to 0} x\sin(\frac{1}{x})=0$$

Answer (score 0):

We only need to know that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, therefore 
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2\sin\frac1x}{\sin x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\sin x}x\sin \frac1x\sin x=\lim_{x\to 0}\underbrace{\frac{x}{\sin x}}_{\to 1}\underbrace{\frac{\sin \frac1x}{\frac1x}}_{\to 1}\underbrace{\sin}_{\to 0} x=0.$$